# Angular 6 NGRX; multipe features sharing selectors

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an architectural question which I am running into while building (and learning!!) my MeteorJS app using Angular 6 and NGRX.

I based my Redux architecture on the brilliant Todd Moto [example](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngrx-store-effects-app/tree/27-testing-effects/src) in which he creates a Pizza designer.
However, he only defined one feature branch called `Products`.
So what if I add another Feature branch, called Oven.

The Oven would like to bake the pizza's that are in the Queue.

The state tree looks like:

```
/
products
..pizzas
....toppings
..queue
oven
..baking
..served
```

The Oven module would have access to the Redux Store, however, it can't simply re-use the reducers and selectors that are defined in the Store folder under the `Products` feature.
For starters, the oven would like to see which pizza's are in the queue, so that they can be put in the oven.

Since the Products feature has it's `ProductsState` defined in the `reducers/index.ts`, I decided to create an AppState and put that under the `app/store` folder. This appState then exposes the features (and will look the same as the store).

Sharing the selectors between features isn't possible, so I assume I would have to create the QueueSelector for both features?
Or would I define selectors that used in both features (not sure if that is already a sign of a bad architecture) in under the `app/store` folders  and don't turn them into feature selectors?

Or should Queue become it's own feature and can you then have features call other features reducers?

I would love to get some advice on best practices in a multi feature NGRX application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would do a separate feature 'queue'.  But calling other feature reducers from there sounds like an architecture smell to me. I would try to avoid that.

Comment: @RenéWinkler Yeah, each feature should be nicely decoupled. So instead, I just tried to add the Queue to the root, in the App itself. Since Feature A puts something in the queue of the root, Feature B can look if that value is available in the root via a selector. This works fine, other then that I can't use a featureSelector in my reducers index.ts file. Instead I used a function: `export const getAppState = ( state: AppState ) => state;` which is then used in my QueueState selector. I am not sure if this is good practice, hence the question. I am getting a bit confused.